# Axios success/error calls with redux-promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a redux application that makes several calls to various apis using axios. I now want to add on a loading bar, but I don't want to add the complexity of redux-thunk. However, in searching googles, it appears that is the optimal way, so you can call dispatch with a type and payload. Is there any simpler way of doing this with a flat object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the redux-thunk or sagas but if you don't want to increase the complexity then the other work around is maintaining the state `isLoading` of the component. So you can toggle this state in the life cycle hooks of the react and render your data. The following is the sample for the workaround that you might be looking for.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) 
        this.state = { isLoading: true }
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        //After doing api stuffs or fetching data toggle state.
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }

    render() {
       this.state.isLoading ? <LoadingScreen/> : <Page/>
    }
}
```

Here `<LoadingScreen/>` has the code for loader while Page component has the code for your Example Component.

Comment: this is the answer I am looking for. It is a solution. But I think I may need to use thunk, seems like that is the only way to do it in a redux way inside the action creator. I wished I knew that before I implemented redux-promise.